# WCH-link, device not found

Tags: embedded

I am working on a project that uses the CH32v307 board.
When I connected the board the driver of the WCH-link is not installed.

I tried searching the internet and could not arrive at any solution.

[image: WCH-link driver not installed]

even on the WCH webpage, I could not get any compatible driver.

Does anyone have experience with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the driver. I was able to update it by selecting the driver search folder: C:\MounRiver\MounRiver_Studio

Answer (score 1):

for debugging multiple wch-link connected ch32v003 or ch32v30x you can use this openocd which supports multiple wch-linke debugger.

https://github.com/123swk123/openocd-wch-linke-multilink

openocd that comes with mounriver does not support multi-instance debugging.